Non-Linear Image Transformation (cube map to fisheye)
I have six images for a cube map
(first row: B, F, D, and
second row: L, R, U sides):






By stacking these sides as show below I created 5 side image.
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

u = cv.rotate(cv.imread(...), cv.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
b = cv.rotate(cv.imread(...), cv.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE)
l = cv.rotate(cv.imread(...), cv.ROTATE_180)
f = cv.rotate(cv.imread(...), cv.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
d = cv.imread(...)
r = cv.imread(...)
_ = np.zeros_like(r)

panorama = np.vstack([
     np.hstack([_, l, _]),
     np.hstack([f, u, b]),
     np.hstack([_, r, _])
])

Output image:

I want to create a fisheye image using this output image, I tried affine and perspective transformations using opencv library, but they preserved the lines and did not work.
What I want to achieve is more like bending and warping the image to transform image borders to curves as this image:


I also tried to use cv.remap but could not figure out how to remap each pixel since there is not a function I can use in my case.
Optional: If I can figure out how to create a fisheye image, I also want to add image D to the outer circle of the image

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_mapping

Please do not post images of code.

you need two relationships and the transforms among each relationship: (1) spherical to cubemap (2) spherical to desired fisheye. then you can look up pixels for your desired fisheye, through spherical, from the cube map.

same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78287555/panorama-to-fisheye -- [tour], [ask], [mre]

and you might wanna post proper data. the first picture you presented has the pictures not being square, and with those red borders.

here's a result picture from the original (higher resolution) picture: https://i.sstatic.net/8uJHG.jpg this is just mapping azimuth = azimuth, altitude ~ radius (NOT fisheye). the gray in the corners is literally coming from the downward facing picture. -- this was made with a bunch of custom code, accelerated with numba.

if your class is on computer graphics (not vision), you should just display six quads textured with the pictures you were given, then place a camera inside of the cube.

equirectangular projection: https://i.sstatic.net/NK3c1.jpg

some googling says that the first map I made is called "polar azimuthal equidistant", fyi

Is it possible you could share your code for azimuthal mapping? @ChristophRackwitz

First convert image parts into cubic projection: https://i.sstatic.net/B7erv.jpg, then convert from the cubic projection to equirectangular projection: https://i.sstatic.net/1XpJc.jpg, then you can easly convert equirectangular image into the fisheye image: https://i.sstatic.net/HimWj.jpg. If you strip bottom part on your equiractangular projection image, the fisheye becomes clearer for further processing calculations: https://i.sstatic.net/nN8Cs.jpg.

looks like you are both in the same class, and sukruburakcetin figured out the assignment. I didn't find high-res sources of those pictures on the internet. -- @sukruburakcetin your last two pictures appear mirrored. the man on the road is supposed to walk to the left :)

@Christop Rackwitz I simply trimmed the last part of the image url link after question mark(?s=128), so you can get higher resolution version of the images. :)

@Christop Rackwitz First, I had written a code that converts planar panorama images to fisheye images, but it didn't succeed because planar panorama images, unlike spherically projected panoramic images, don't include areas for all regions (they don't include the top/upper, or bottom/down portion of the panorama, hence not encompassing the sky). However, a solution as described above can be devised. Yet, I'm not sure if directly transforming a sample panorama image into a fisheye image or first converting it to an equirectangular projection and then fisheye would yield the same result.

@ChristophRackwitz How did you manage to produce high-quality result examples without accessing higher resolution images? When I first saw them, I was quite surprised and initially thought you also re-saved the images through link manipulation, like I did. By the way, what approaches did you follow when generating fisheye images? Do you think my method is correct? I agree with you about the mirroring aspect; I guess I need to reconsider that. But did your method involve projection transformation like mine, or did you convert directly without any projection transformation?

my first comment was to suggest the calculation from source to destination, not to have an intermediate image. it is certainly possible (and I have done it) to generate arbitrary projections from a cubemap, without intermediate images. -- the first revision of this question contained slightly (!) better images, but with those red lines drawn on top of them, probably by hand because one of them doesn't align properly. when I'm at home, I'll definitely use the full res cubemap faces and regenerate. this is a fun problem to me because I'm in no rush (no deadline), just toying with it.

I didn't attempt to generate a fisheye image. I just played with the cubemap, the math, my understanding of it. the first few attempts just gave me "identity" maps of one of the faces. then I tried to just map angles. equirectangular and "polar azimuthal equidistant" are related maps in that they map angles linearly. my one PAE map is scaled such that it spans pi, but then I added another factor of 1.5 to it, so it spans more than 180 degrees, but not 360 degrees of altitude. -- generating a fisheye image should be easy, given an arbitrary but mathematically defined fisheye lens model.

transformations are inherently involved in mapping. there's no mapping without that. my code runs over the output image space (to sample the source of each output pixel), maps those coordinates to spherical coordinates, then a unit vector, and then to the face and uv coordinates in the cubemap. yes, this requires sampling from any of the six faces of the cubemap. placing them all in a single image may be recommended for cv::remap() but it makes uv calculations a little more involved (mapping from face to its place in the texture)

perhaps you'd like to play with "shadertoy". there are many examples of using cubemaps for it. here are two: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XsjfDD and https://www.shadertoy.com/view/7d2XD3

here's the tiles downsampled severely, then drawn with nearest neighbor sampling. this can give you a feeling for how the faces of the cube map to the projections https://i.sstatic.net/1Dhvc.jpg
https://i.sstatic.net/lPhPy.jpg
